# Why does the first line in the reduce asynchronous function run multiple times before the remaining lines?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have the below piece of code, I run it as it is, `node filename.js`, node version 14.16.0.

```js
(async () => {

  const add2 = a => a + 2;
  const mult3 = a => a * 3;
  const square = a => a * a;
  const asyncAdd3 = a => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(a), 100));
  // composedFunc(2);
  
  // Implement compose
  const compose = (...args) => {
    return (value) => {
      return args.reduce(async (value, fn) => {
        console.log(1);
        var resolvedValue = await value;
        console.log(2);
        const returnVal = await fn(resolvedValue);
        console.log(3);
        return returnVal;
      }, value)
    }
  }
  
  const composedFunc = compose(add2, mult3, square, asyncAdd3);

  console.log(await composedFunc(2));
})();
```

The output is as follows:

```
1
1
1
1
2
3
2
3
2
3
2
3
144
```

I don't understand why 1 gets printed four times before it goes to 2 and 3.. the below is what I was expecting to happen:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
144
```

Comment: This is why you should not use `reduce` with an `async` callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `reduce` takes the first value from the array and calls the callback with it (the current value) and the initial value (the accumulator).
2. The callback logs `1`
3. The callback reaches an `await` statement next to a promise so it **goes to sleep** while it waits for the promise to resolve
4. A promise is returned to the calling function (the internals of `reduce`)
5. `reduce` takes the *second* value from the array and calls the callback with it (the current value) and the Promise that was returned by the previous step (the accumulator).

And so on.

When it gets to the end of the array, and everything else synchronous has finished, then the event loop checks to see if any Promises have resolved. At that point the *first* instance of the callback is woken up again.

---

You can't usefully use asynchronous functions as the callback for `reduce`.

Often you can use `const resulting_array = await Promise.all( your_array.map( async_function ) )` to get a list of values and **then** use `resulting_array.reduce()`.

Comment: Or in this case, where sequential calls are desired, just `for (const fn of args) value = await fn(value); return value`